# In R, how do you compare two columns with a regex, row-by row?

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I have a data frame (a tibble, actually) `df`, with two columns, `a` and `b`, and I want to filter out the rows in which `a` is a substring of `b`. I've tried

```
df %>%
  dplyr::filter(grepl(a,b))
```

but I get a warning that seems to indicate that R is actually applying `grepl` with the first argument being the *whole* column `a`.

> Is there any way to apply a regular expression involving two different columns to each row in a tibble (or data frame)?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used for testing. But `grepl` isn't vectorized over the pattern. Perhaps use some `map/Map/mapply` function to help with that.

Comment: `I get a warning that seems to indicate that R is actually applying grepl with the first argument being the whole column` Actually in this case only the first element is used, not the whole column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're only interested in by-row comparisons, you can use `rowwise()`:

```
df <- data.frame(A=letters[1:5],
             B=paste0(letters[3:7],letters[c(2,2,4,3,5)]),
             stringsAsFactors=F)

df %>% 
   rowwise() %>% 
   filter(grepl(A,B))

       A      B
1      b     db
2      e     ge
```

**---------------------------------------------------------------------------------**
If you want to know whether `row-entry of A` is in `all of B`:

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% filter(any(grepl(A,df$B)))

      A     B
1     b    db
2     c    ed
3     d    fc
4     e    ge
```

Answer (score 1):

Or using base R apply and @Chi-Pak's reproducible example

```
df <- data.frame(A=letters[1:5],
                 B=paste0(letters[3:7],letters[c(2,2,4,3,5)]),
                 stringsAsFactors=F)

matched <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) grepl(df$A[i], df$B[i]))

df[matched, ]
```

Result

```
  A  B
2 b db
5 e ge
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`stringr::str_detect`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/topics/str_detect), which is vectorised over both string and pattern. (Whereas, as you noted, `grepl` is only vectorised over its string argument.)

Using @Chi Pak's example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  filter(str_detect(B, fixed(A)))
#   A  B
# 1 b db
# 2 e ge
```